# How to locate a section of a PDF and save as PNG, in python?

Tags: python, pdf

I'd like to automatically locate a section of a PDF and save it as a PNG. I'm assuming that, by locating the text of the header at the start of the section and working out its page and 'Y' coordinate and by doing the same for the text of the subsequent header, I might then be able to grab an image from 0,Y1 to <page_width>,Y2.

I'm a bit of a newbie to Python but have found PyPDF, pdfminer and pdfplumber - I'm hoping one (or a combination) of these might do the job. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Recommending package PyMuPDF. It combines advanced possibilities for text searching and extraction with the ease of taking pictures of (parts of) a document page (PDF or a handful of more formats: XPS; EPUB,...). Example of a picture: Define rectangle `rect = fitz.Rect(0, y1, page.rect.width, y2)`, then do `pix = page.get_pixmap(clip=rect)` which is a raw image of that rectangle, then save to a PNG image: `pix.save("test.png")`. DONE

Comment: As mentioned, you can extract text already pre-arranged in (sort of) paragraphs: `blocks = page.get_text("blocks")`, Each item of the resulting list contains the paragraph lines and the rectangle wrapping them. If your string is part of the text lines in item `(x0, y0, x1, y1, "line1\nline2\n...")` you already have all you need for making the image. Many more options are available for refining this. Feel free to visit this channel: https://discord.com/channels/770681584617652264/983871937711341618.